# find first match looking back from element in vector r

Tags: r, time-series, match

I have a time series where I identified the local maxima. Now I want to find the indices of the first elements with a value of zero looking back from the maxima. E.g.

```
my.seq <- c(sin(0:(2*pi)), rep(0, 5), sin(seq(0, (2*pi), 0.5)))
```

local maxima:

```
indx.max <- c(3, 16)
```

I want to get:

```
c(1, 13)
```

Thanks

Comment: Why `c(3, 13)`? Shouldn't it be `c(1,13)`? Guess I'm missing something. If I am not, try `x<-which(my.seq==0);x[findInterval(indx.max,x)]`.

Comment: oops, you're right. My bad. Thanks for the tip; didn't know about findInterval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
x<-which(my.seq==0)
x[findInterval(indx.max,x)]
#[1]  1 13
```